# Iphone - Notify from the server to the client when an event occurs

Tags: ios, xmpp

im stuck in a situation

**SITUATION :** I have a situation wherein i answer some questions and get points according to the answered questions. if my points become say 10 i win some gift using a QRCode. **(there is a qr code that is generated to the user, and when the qrcode is scanned from someother device which has a scanner app or any other scanner, it gives a link to that online store. This link can be opened from any browser.)** The gift is accessed from some online store by scanning the QRCode which gives a link to that online store with some unique id and when the gift is accessed/taken the server is notified that the gift is accessed/taken from that online gift store and the QRCode status is updated to invalid on the server database. Now once the server gets the notification that the gift is being accessed/taken, the server should immediately notify my iphone app that the gift is received so that i can immediately show another congratulations image or something.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION :** i thought of one possible solution wherein i check upon the qrcode access status change on the server every say 60 secs and display the image accordingly. I dont know how efficient/correct this way would be though.

**ISSUE :** but before i refuge to the above solution, i want to know, can this notification happen from the server without my app trying to call or fetch the update from the server? I mean, my app comes into the picture only after the server sends a notification in the form of a msg or some xml or something..

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Apple Push Notification Service is meant to solve these types of situations. Hope it helps: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a connection to your server using `CFReadStream`, add the stream to your runloop and set up a callback function. Whenever the server writes data to the open connection, your callback will fire and you can then read from the stream to get the data the server sent

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFStreamTasks/CFStreamTasks.html

Comment: interesting... will check upon this

Comment: r there any tutorials to use this apart from apple documentation??

Comment: i'll write one up later today if you still want one, but the logic is as follows: 

Create stream, add stream to runloop, set stream callback function.

Each of the previous tasks maps to 1 specific function, you don't have to write a lot of code to use this

Comment: im trying to apply the logic.. but it would be great if you could give me a lil code.. so that i can compare what i have done with urs.. great help man thanks.. :) since there are hardly any proper tutorials or reference to this apart from the documentation u will be helping a lot of others looking for this too...

Comment: Is your remote server an HTTP server or just a plain TCP server?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to check [Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html). But it's impossible to determine on server side if notification was received on client side or not (if you won't implement it by yourself, but you'll probably wont cover all the possible situations, like when your app is not launched and notification came).

Comment: no i guess u got it wrong.. 1st the server will get notified, then once it is notified, server should inform the client(my app) that there has been an update in the status.

Comment: You should update your question and get into the details more deeply. Do you mean that you are opening that gift link in iPhone on safari and after that you're unable to get back to app? You may use custom url schemes than.
Anyway this mine last comment seems for me not connected to what you've asked=) So please explain, push notifications seems to be good for notifying client iOS app about anything even if app was killed on the device

Comment: if the qrcode scanner is an iphone then safari, if its some android or someother devoce it is its respective browser.. n i think i have given a detailed explaination.. just check out.. i added an edit

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use XMPP protocol, which is most commonly used for chats/mails, where the changes in the server is notified to the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Push Notification Service is meant to solve these types of situations.

Hope it helps: 
Apple Docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

There is a nice tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKV5csbueHA&feature=relmfu

Comment: i mean push notification will not solve my problem.. its not the answer im looking for.. sorry.. :(